# SSRS - Chart - Remove gaps caused by data

Tags: reporting-services, bar-chart

I need help with trying to remove gaps from my Bar chart.

Dataset Query:

```
SELECT 'Excused' as Type, '9120' as Total, '< 5' as CountRange
UNION
SELECT 'Unexcused' as Type, '11540' as Total, '< 5' as CountRange
UNION
SELECT 'Excused' as Type, '10990' as Total, '5 - 9' as CountRange
UNION
SELECT 'Unexcused' as Type, '2966' as Total, '5 - 9' as CountRange
UNION
SELECT 'Excused' as Type, '6513' as Total, '10 - 14' as CountRange
UNION
SELECT 'Unexcused' as Type, '1101' as Total, '10 - 14' as CountRange
UNION
SELECT 'Excused' as Type, '3277' as Total, '15 - 20' as CountRange
UNION
SELECT 'Unexcused' as Type, '537' as Total, '15 - 20' as CountRange
UNION
SELECT 'Excused' as Type, '2195' as Total, '> 20' as CountRange
UNION
SELECT 'Unexcused' as Type, '627' as Total, '> 20' as CountRange
UNION
SELECT 'Perfect Attendance' as Type, '1401' as Total, ' ' as CountRange
```

Datafield = Total   (not Count(Total) which is the default)

Series = Type

Category = CountRange

If I remove the last UNION that has 'Perfect Attendance' the Category Grouping is exactly how I want it to look.  When I introduce the last UNION it then gives me a blank colum on every category grouping.  It also gives me two blanks on the last grouping as well.

Ive tried multiple ways to try to filter out the blanks that happen because of the last union, but I cant seem to find the right way to do this.  SSRS is not where I normally work so this could be something really easy that I havent stumbled upon yet, or used the correct keywords when searching for a solution.

The outcome I want is to see '< 5', '5 - 9', '10 -14', '15 - 20', and '> 20' all have 'Excused' and 'Unexcused' bars, and then ' ' have it's own bar for 'Perfect Attendance' at the end.  Currently it looks like there's an extra bar for 'Perfect Attendance' on each grouping.

[image: Chart With Gaps]
[image: Older Image, but ideal Way That I'd like to see the data show up]

Answer (score 0):

A stacked bar graph would give the sort of effect you are after, as long as that was appropriate for your needs:

[image]